# guest checkout not enabled in live but in sandbox for same nvpstr

Tags: paypal

i am facing two different behavior of paypal for same nvpstr. when i set paypal mode to SANDBOX it works perfect(customers are able to pay with credit card only) but when i switch SANDBOX to LIVE pay with credit card goes out. What's wrong in my code and why for same NVPSTR pay only by credit card is accepted and in live it force me to create paypal account? here is my NVPSTR

```
&L_NAME0=Nausea Relief Tea&L_AMT0=8.50&L_QTY0=1&L_NUMBER0=15&L_DESC0=Get fast relief from nausea and upset stomach with my Nausea Relief Tea. &MAXAMT=39.45&AMT=14.45&ITEMAMT=8.5&CALLBACKTIMEOUT=4&ADDRESSOVERRIDE=0&SHIPTONAME=Jackson Pollick&SHIPTOSTREET=440 Benmar Suite 204&SHIPTOCITY=&SHIPTOSTATE=&SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=&SHIPTOZIP=77060&NOSHIPPING=0&SHIPPINGAMT=5.95&SHIPDISCAMT=0&TAXAMT=0&**SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole&LANDINGPAGE=Billing**&ReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.my-site.com%3A80%2Fpaypal_multiple_product%2FReviewOrder.php%3FcurrencyCodeType%3DUSD%26paymentType%3DSale&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.my-site.com%3A80%2Fpaypal_multiple_product%2FSetExpressCheckout.php%3FpaymentType%3DSale&CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&LOGOIMG=images/logo.gif&useraction=commit
```

any idea of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PayPal is moving to a new version of the EC checkout pages and they've removed the ability to force the full credit card form.  Very frustrating, and myself and others have been voicing our concerns, but they haven't made any changes to their decision at this point.  I believe they're trying to get people to sign up for Advanced or Pro.